# Which is should I use and why? Does it matter? SafeUnicode or django.utils.safestring.mark_safe()?

Tags: python, django, string

Suppose I've got a custom form label with some HTML on it like so:

```
SafeUnicode('<span class="superscript">&trade;</span>')
```

Why would Django 1.2 have a function mark_safe if this exist? What are the differences if any?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mark_safe` is a factory function which encapsulate a bit of type-checking logic in order to return, as appropriate, either a `SafeUnicode` or a `SafeString` (or possibly some other subclass of `SafeData` should you have defined any such subclasses).  The [source](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/safestring.py) is easily short enough to quote...:

```
89  def mark_safe(s):
90      """
91      Explicitly mark a string as safe for (HTML) output purposes. The returned
92      object can be used everywhere a string or unicode object is appropriate.
93  
94      Can be called multiple times on a single string.
95      """
96      if isinstance(s, SafeData):
97          return s
98      if isinstance(s, str) or (isinstance(s, Promise) and s._delegate_str):
99          return SafeString(s)
100     if isinstance(s, (unicode, Promise)):
101         return SafeUnicode(s)
102     return SafeString(str(s))
```

Just using `SafeUnicode(s)` instead of `make_safe(s)` will be minutely faster, but could get you in trouble if you're potentially dealing with a type and value that don't happily support being passed to the `SafeUnicode` initializer (e.g., a byte string with non-ascii codes, a non-string, a `Promise` with a string delegate, ...).  If you are 100% certain that you know what you're doing, nothing stops you from going for the nanoseconds-saving approach;-).

By the way, some questions about open-source code (no matter how well documented, and Django's docs are really impressive) are often best answered by first having a look at the code (and then asking if the code's too complex or subtle to follow with assurance).

Comment: +1 for looking at the source. Django's source makes for pretty good docs when the regular docs don't explain something. Python is pretty readable.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question so thoroughly yet concisely. I appreciate your valuable advice as well. It's so much like one of my favorite proverbs: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"

Comment: Paul, +1 chiming in with the support. I love Python. It's readability and great community are only two of the many reasons I recently switched from C# and ASP.NET to Django and Python :) Thanks again!